# SQL takes 2min to perform query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

As the title says. I have a SQL question that takes about 2 min to perform.
The SQL Question looks like this:

```
SELECT *,
(SELECT (CASE WHEN `Grupp_ID` > 0 THEN `Grupp_Name` ELSE  `Customers`.`Customer` END) AS `Cust` FROM `Customers` WHERE `Customers`.`ID` = `ordrar`.`CustomerNr`) AS `GruppName`,
(SELECT SUM(REPLACE(`Hours`,',','.')) FROM `anarbetstid` WHERE `order` = `ordrar`.`order`) AS `Hours`,
(SELECT SUM(REPLACE(`Amount`,',','.')) FROM `Resa` WHERE `order` = `ordrar`.`order`) AS `Resor`,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `anmaterial` WHERE `Order` = `ordrar`.`order`) AS `Material`,
(SELECT SUM(REPLACE(`Hours`,',','.') * (SELECT REPLACE(`TimePrice`,',','.') FROM `Arbetstid` WHERE `TimeCode` = `anarbetstid`.`TimeCode`)) FROM `anarbetstid` WHERE `order` = `ordrar`.`order`) AS `TimmarSum`,
(SELECT SUM(REPLACE(`Antal`,',','.') * (SELECT REPLACE(`Price`,',','.') FROM `reselist` WHERE `ID` = `Resa`.`Restyp`)) FROM `Resa` WHERE `order` = `ordrar`.`order`) AS `ResorSum`,
(SELECT CASE `palagg` WHEN 0 THEN SUM((REPLACE(`Rabatt`,',','.') * REPLACE(`Price`,',','.')) * REPLACE(`Amount`,',','.'))
WHEN 1 THEN SUM((REPLACE(`Rabatt`,',','.') * REPLACE(`InPrice`,',','.')) * REPLACE(`Amount`,',','.'))
ELSE 0
END

FROM `anmaterial` 
WHERE `Order` = `ordrar`.`order`) AS `MaterialSum` 
FROM `ordrar` 
WHERE `ordertyp` = '3' group by `ordrar`.`order` ORDER BY `ordrar`.`ID` ASC
```

if i remove "group by `ordrar`.`order`" I can get it to run in about 1 min.

Each table has around 4000 rows.

Can someone help me spot the problem why it takes so long time to perform this query?

Comment: do your table are properly indexed

Comment: Can you show explain command output for this query?

Comment: Thanks @KarthickKumar i forgot to index 2 of the tables. that slowed everything down dramatically.

Answer (score 0):

Why you not use LEFT JOIN? I think problem in this

```
SELECT *, 
(CASE WHEN `Grupp_ID` > 0 THEN `Grupp_Name` ELSE  `Customers`.`Customer` END) AS `Cust` 
...
LEFT JOIN `Customers` ON `Customers`.`ID` = `ordrar`.`CustomerNr`
...
FROM `ordrar` 
WHERE `ordertyp` = '3' group by `ordrar`.`order` ORDER BY `ordrar`.`ID` ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to index 2 of the tables. that slowed everything down dramatically.

Thanks again Karthick Kumar!